# How to get a jquery nav bar to load information in a div tag?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html

Im using jquery on my nav bar but i want to get it to load information in one of my div tags  anything i need to add into my nav bar that is running with jquery/ajax to load in the div and what should i add on the div tag to make it function the same. my site is.

http://www.horimonotattoo.com

Comment: You can use the `.load()` method to load some HTML content in a specific container. take a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: im not very diverse in using java so this is all a blur to me. kinda need a little more in the sense of how to get it to work in my situation. for example if i use a html file that will load in the div what code should i add to my <li><a href="misc.html">Miscellaneous</a></li> for example or do i need to add something to my <style> to get it to function with the load

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but perhaps this will be of some help. 
You can use jQuery to add a div to your page when clicking a link as follows.

```
<head>
<!-- include jquery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- run a script for when a button or element is clicked -->
<script type="text/javascript">

//when page has loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
//when link with class name 'linkClassName' is clicked
    $('.linkClassName').click(function(){
    //add a div after the </a> tag
    $(this).append('<div>hello</div>');
});//end click function
});//end document ready

</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#" class="linkClassName">Click Me</a>

</body>
```

a working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/nskWD/1/

you can also use .load(url) in the click function to load an entire page into a div,

$('#divId').load(url);

Comment: thats a lot like what i was wanting but i wanted was a lot  more then just a phrase hello. i almost wanted to make it seem like i was loading a iframe but not an iframe. i want to click tattoos and it loads on my right column a div that is filled with all the tattoo gallery while staying in the same page. so loading content without refreshing the page to another page. in turn by doing this i dont want the nav bar to refresh after going to another page.

Comment: only problem with what you have there is adding a whole lot of info into a style tag wouldnt be very good. is there a way i can call upon the info inside the html. because i need to put a lot of information in there including jquery colorbox/lighttbox

Comment: you should be able to use the .load(url) selector to load the contents of another page into your div. I have updated the answer, see the bottom. You may need to research this a bit. It may only work with relative files, not other sites. But this may not be an issue for your purposes.